# Working with localization in ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-localization

I am trying to implement localization in our application, but I just cannot get it to work. My problem is how can I set the culture properly and how can access the localization string as per the culture set.

I am trying to set the culture from dropdownlist which is at the login page and pulling the resources from database.

**Startup file**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddSqlLocalization(options => options.UseTypeFullNames = true);

        services.AddMvc(o =>
        {
            o.Filters.Add(new LanguageActionFilter());
        })
        .AddViewLocalization()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());


        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
             options =>
             {
                 var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                     {
                         new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                        new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                       new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),

                     };

                 options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
                 options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                 options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
             });

    }
```

**Controller code**:- Calling from dropdown index changed through ajax.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture)
    {

            AppTenant tenant = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<AppTenant>("TenantInfo");

            if (tenant != null)
            {
                tenant.LoggedInCulture = strdata[0];
                HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("TenantInfo", tenant);

                string cookieFormat = "culture-name";
                string cookieVal = cookieFormat.Replace("culture-name", tenant.LoggedInCulture);

                Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(cookieVal)),
                new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMonths(3) }
               );
            }


        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<List<SelectListItem>>("LanguageData");

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.Value == culture)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                item.Selected = false;
            }
        }
        var viewModel = new LMS_User { ReturnUrl = string.Empty, LanguageList = items };

        return View("Login", viewModel);

    }
```

**Resource Filter**:- Here I have tried to set the culture in `OnResourceExecuting` and `OnResourceExecuted` method like follow.

```
public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
       AppTenant tenant = context.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<AppTenant>("TenantInfo");

        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(_culture);
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(_culture);
    }
```

In Resource filter where should we set the culture as I am not getting the current dropdown value in `OnResourceExecuting` but getting in `OnResourceExecuted` through session.

My `SqlStringLocalizerFactory` class where pulling resource from database

```
public class SqlStringLocalizerFactory : IStringLocalizerFactory, IStringExtendedLocalizerFactory
{
public IStringLocalizer Create(Type resourceSource)
    {

        SqlStringLocalizer sqlStringLocalizer;

        _culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString();
}
```

Here I want to get the selected culture, which is I am not getting it, it is coming as 'en-US'

Any help on this appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change current thread Culture and UICulture properties to required culture. Add following code to your SetLanguage action and that should solve your issue:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new  System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureInfo ); 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureInfo );
```

Comment: @Rohit This is how I has been dealing with localization task, when I had to switch languages for the app I've been working on. So I know for the fact, that this way job would be done. I think you need to make sure, that UICulture on a thread has been actually changed. It looks like it had not been.